# Function to return a response in NodeJS controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a controller where I am trying to return a response to the user but it's unable to send response and value is showing in console.

Below is my code:

```
const hubHome = (req,res) => {

  const hubId = req.params.hubId;

  fetchData(hubId);
}

const fetchData = (id) => {
  console.log(`Hub id is ${id}`);
  return res.status(200).send(`Hub id is ${id}`);
}

module.exports = hubHome;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `res` object is not within the scope of `fetchData`. To fix this, add another parameter to `fetchData`.

```
const hubHome = (req,res) => {

  const hubId = req.params.hubId;

  fetchData(hubId, res);
}

const fetchData = (id, res) => {
  console.log(`Hub id is ${id}`);
  return res.status(200).send(`Hub id is ${id}`);
}

module.exports = hubHome;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked i havn't passed `res` as a parameter in my function.